# Why safari does not cache dynamically inserted image elements?

Tags: jquery, image, safari, loading

Please check the snippet below. When run in chrome/firefox the dynamically inserted image is not requested every time since the src is not changing, but when run in safari the image is requested as many times as the button is clicked. What is wrong with this? I was expecting the image to not load every time it is removed and added back to the DOM. Please suggest any workaround for consistent behaviour across browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.test').remove()
    var im = $('<img class="test" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100?random&126"/>')
    im.appendTo($('body'))
  })
  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <button>insert</button>
  <br>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this in the end? If you were, please provide your solution below as this appears to be a common issue.